# Problems using just_audiio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, just-audio

I have been experimenting with just_audio playing internet audio streams. I can play BBC World service using this address: *https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/dash/nonuk/
dash_low/aks/bbc_world_service.mpd*
but using a different address : *https://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_world_service* I get the following errors:

```
ExoPlayerImpl( 4556): Init d22c684 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [generic_x86_arm, sdk_gphone_x86_arm, Google, 30]
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:579)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT qÆTÆXq�V��ۄ�$��d...@1:111 in java.io.InputStreamReader@5a94cdd)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:107)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:62)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:179)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4556):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
```

Both addresses play on VLC.
Can anyone explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: If I replace the URL with that one in the official just_audio example, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first URL is Dash but the second one is not but I had unfortunately marked it as such: just_audio works fine with both streams!